# Is there a GUI to display a file from a remote git repository without cloning it?

Tags: linux, file-management, git

If I want to look inside a file in a remote repository, is this possible without cloning the whole repository?

I tried

```
git ls-remote git@remoteserver.com:repo.git
```

but that only displays references available in a remote repository along with the associated commit IDs.

There is a solution on the console [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository) but that is quite complicated and not very handy to use on multiple files. You can see the content in some certain file (for ex. `ìndex.php`) this way.

Optimal for me would be a sort of file-browser (like Krusader) **on Linux**, where I would just enter the git url `git@remoteserver.com:repo.git` and can browse all files inside the repository.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Use something as [gitweb](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-6.html) in the pc that have the original repository.

### Option 2

If you can't do that, you can make a [shallow clone](http://mortalpowers.com/news/speed-up-git-clone-with-shallow-clones) with depth=1 that should be as fast as downloading an snapshot.

### Option 3

If you don't want that it will depend on the actual protocol you are using to get the repo, usually it is ssh or http, so you can mount a virtual file-system pointing there with the right credentials.

### Alternative

May be you should be looking for a service like [github](https://github.com) that will help browsing repos without download.

Comment: Option 1 might be understood as "install github webapp in the pc that have the original repository", which is impossible. A clarification would be welcome.

Comment: Option 3 is a good idea, a bit of details could be useful. The repo is `git@remoteserver.com:repo.git` so the protocol is SSH.

Comment: That's why I say that gitweb can be used instead of github.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I moved github as an alternative approach.